# jquery datatable is returning second last row instead of last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm working on an application which uses jquery datatable and I reload the jquery datatable after user insert something everything working perfect except the following piece of code:

```
$.when( myDataTable.ajax.reload(null, false) ).done(function() {
    var last_row = myDataTable.row(':last').data();
    console.log(last_row);
});
```

It should return the last row data object but what I get is the second last row data object. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it wrong as per the description of https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() there is a call back that can be called when the reload is finished. Happy Hack!

**Updated Coded is**

```
myDataTable.ajax.reload(function(){
      var last_row = myDataTable.row(':last').data();
      console.log(last_row);
}, false));
```